# Currency value API PHP

Tags: php, xml, json, api, currency

whence I can get actual currency values? I want get data in JSON format or XML. I can't find it in Google:
http://www.xe.com/tools.php
https://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/get-live-currency-value-using-yahoo-api/https://openexchangerates.org/documentation

I want to free use in PHP. Which is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say which is best but here is a resource I have used from time to time:

https://openexchangerates.org/

Additionally this works really well with the javascript mini-library [money.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/)